# XSLT: need help how to add a new attribute to an existing element that will contain incremental values

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, increment

XSLT: need help how to add a new attribute (id) to an existing element (row) that will contain incremental values.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Personal>
    <description />
    <details />
    <information>
        <Table>
            <Location>
                <location>town</location>
                <location>city</location>
                <location>country</location>
            </Location>
            <Contact>
                <row>
                    <values>
                        <ref id="0" value="name" />
                        <ref id="1" value="address" />
                    </values>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <values>
                        <ref id="0" value="name" />
                        <ref id="1" value="" />
                        <ref id="2" value="" />
                    </values>
                </row>
            </Contact>
        </Table>
    </information>
</Personal>
```

Desired Output:

To have an id attribute in row element wherein the values will increment from 0 onwards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Personal>
    <description />
    <details />
    <information>
        <Table>
            <Location>
                <location>town</location>
                <location>city</location>
                <location>country</location>
            </Location>
            <Contact>
                <row id="0">
                    <values>
                        <ref id="0" value="name" />
                        <ref id="1" value="address" />
                    </values>
                </row>
                <row id="1">
                    <values>
                        <ref id="0" value="name" />
                        <ref id="1" value="" />
                        <ref id="2" value="" />
                    </values>
                </row>
            </Contact>
        </Table>
    </information>
</Personal>
```

I'm new to XSLT and everything I tried does not seem to work at all

Comment: Can the input contain more than one `Contact` element? If yes, should the `row` numbers restart?

Comment: Only one Contact element. Anyway, this is resolved :)

Comment: Don't tell us you tried everything and nothing worked. Tell us one thing you tried, and tell us how it failed. That way we can see what you're doing wrong, and help you up the learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That transform looks simple enough that you could just use `position()`...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <row id="{position()-1}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're unable to use XSLT 3.0, just replace xsl:mode with the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying).

Working fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MP42Nt